# Error at generic helper function for reading JSON from an URL

Tags: json, swift

In one of my projects, I want to read JSON from several URLs in several Views into several structs so I decided to write a small, but generic helper function.

This function should be called e.g.

View 1:

```
let call1 = Bundle.main.decode(iobrokerSection.self, from: "http://192.168.1.205:8087/get/javascript.0.Fahrzeiten.Dauer")
```

View 2:

```
let call2 = Bundle.main.decodeURL(iobrokerweather.self, from: "http://192.168.1.205:8087/get/javascript.0.Fahrzeiten.Weather")
```

and so on.

For the first example the struct `iobrokerSection` is

```
struct iobrokerNumberDataPoint: Codable {
    var val: Int
    var ack: Bool
    var ts: Int
    var q: Int
    var from: String
    var user: String
    var lc: Int
    var _id: String
    var type: String
}
```

And here is my helper function

```
extension Bundle {
    func decodeURL<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from urlString: String) -> T {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            fatalError("Placeholder for a good error message")
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let loaded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!) else {
                fatalError("Placeholder for a good error message")
            }
        }.resume()

        return loaded
    }
}
```

I think that I understand why I'm getting the compiler message "Cannot convert return expression of type Bool to return Type T" at "return loaded".

But I don't have any idea how to fix this.

May anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it is Swift naming convention to name all your structures, classes and protocols starting with an uppercase letter. Second you can't wait for an asynchronous method to finish to return a value. You need to add a completion handler to your method. Third you don't need to use a URLRequest if your intent is only to get some data. You can just use an URL and pass a URL to your method instead of a string. Fourth don't force unwrap the returned data it might be nil. You need to safely unwrap your optional data and in case of error pass it to the completion handler. Your decode method should look like something like this:

```
extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from url: URL, completion: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            do {
               try completion(JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data), nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

---

When calling this method you need to get the asynchronous result inside the resulting closure:

```
struct IOBrokerNumberDataPoint: Codable {
    var val: Int
    var ack: Bool
    var ts: Int
    var q: Int
    var from: String
    var user: String
    var lc: Int
    var id: String
    var type: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case val, ack, ts, q, from, user, lc, id = "_id", type
    }
}
```

---

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.205:8087/get/javascript.0.Fahrzeiten.Dauer")!
Bundle.main.decode(IOBrokerNumberDataPoint.self, from: url) { brokerNumberDataPoint, error in
    guard let brokerNumberDataPoint = brokerNumberDataPoint else {
        print("error", error ?? "")
        return
    }
    print("brokerNumberDataPoint", brokerNumberDataPoint)
    // use brokerNumberDataPoint here
}
```

---

Another option is to use Swift 5 `Result` [generic enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result).

```
extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)) }
                return
            }
            do {
                try completion(.success(JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.205:8087/get/javascript.0.Fahrzeiten.Dauer")!

Bundle.main.decode(from: url) { (result: Result<IOBrokerNumberDataPoint, Error>) in
    switch result {
    case let .success(brokerNumberDataPoint):
        print("brokerNumberDataPoint", brokerNumberDataPoint)
        // use brokerNumberDataPoint here
    case let .failure(error):
        print("error:", error)
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Hi Leo,
thanks a lot for your fast help. Concerning your first topic, you`re absolutely right. I've hacked the code straight forward ignoring the guidelines.

Due to the fact, that I'm programming mostly Java Backend-Systems (JEE, Hibernate etc.) which has mostly sync calls, the combination of SwiftUI, async calls and closures are really a nightmare for me. I think, there's still a lot of learning.