# Initialize a placeholder empty variable of generic type

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift.
My ultimate goal is to return the value `level` (which contains decoded JSON) but I am struggling with returning data from my function.

This is my code:

```swift
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let urlString = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1WMjoHM2iaKjfx9wZhE_6jmKlcMi_OzGT&export=download"
        var level = type;
        self.loadJson(fromURLString: urlString) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                level = try! decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

        return level
    }
```

### Current problem

The current problem is when I try to assign a value to level I get the following error `Cannot assign value of type 'T' to type 'T.Type'`

### What I've tried

My assumption is the error is happening because initializing a variable with T.type is trying to initialize with the name of the Class instead of the Class itself.  I tried to call `type.self` with no luck.

I also tried to get creative to not have to initialize an empty variable.  I tried returning `decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)` but I was getting a weird `Unexpected non-void return value in void function` error.  I have no idea what that is all about.

Is there an easy way to initialize an empty variable to return data later when given T.Type

Comment: You can never return a value from this function. Your code is asynchronous. http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Comment: Thanks, in a previous version, this function was successfully returning data when I was referencing a JSON file on my local hard drive.  I'll take a look at your document to try and figure out an alternative solution.  It never occurred to me that the function would become asynchronous when calling a URL.

Comment: That is what calling a URL is.

Comment: @Nicolasome https://stackoverflow.com/a/63545081/2303865

Comment: The file parameter is not being used. Is this the function as you are actually trying to build it, or an example?